# Excel If a value in cell a2>8 automatically move to cell D2 to enter text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am trying to have a spread sheet to record hours worked so that if the total hours for the day are above 8 in cell `A2`, the cursor is moved automatically to cell `D2` on the second tab so a reason for overtime can be entered.

- Tab one is called 2013
- Tab two is called 2013 overtime.

I'm not very good with excel so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide much information. Which cells get changed and contribute to A2? Are there similar columns that would require a different cell to be selected? Please edit your question and add a few more details about the data structure.

The following macro works on the assumption that cell A2 gets changed manually.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim shOvertime As Worksheet
Set shOvertime = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2013 Overtime")
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("A2") > 8 Then
        shOvertime.Activate
        shOvertime.Range("D2").Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

If your data structure is different, please explain it.

To get the code to work, right-click on the sheet tab and select "View Code" to open the Visual Basic Editor (VBE). Paste the code into the code window and close the VBE. Then enter numbers into cells A2.

Comment: so far the sheet is set upas follows: cell a2 lists the date cell a2 is total hours worked per day (a2 will be entered by individual employees) a3 is start time and a4 is end time. The start and end time will not be edited

Comment: sorry hit enter a little to soon.

Comment: so far the sheet is set up as follows: cell a1 lists the date cell a2 is total hours worked per day (a2 will be entered by each individual) a3 is start time and a4 is end time. The start and end time will not be edited they are set times. For example if I work from 6:30 to 14:30 totaling 8 hours I want to be able to enter 8 into cell a2 without anything happening but if i worked from 06:30 to 15:30 and i type in 9 i am automatically taken to the 2013 overtime tab of the same date so I can type in a reason for the hour over time.

Comment: And does the sheet have just one row for data entry? Is cell A2 the only cell where users enter their hours? I imagine that a time sheet will have more than just one row. How is the overtime sheet related? Do you want a row by row relationship or do you want a contiguous list of overtime only? Come on, describe the picture. Don't let people have to drag the info out of you. And then, please edit the question and put the complete info there. Consider posting a screenshot of the input and the overtime sheet. If you don't have enough rep to include a picture, use a web service.